# R parsing database dumps to find joins

Tags: r

I have a bunch of database dumps to try and figure out.

I have read in my files into a list of dataframes using:

```
filenames <- list.files(path ="./ref_tables", pattern="*.csv" )
file_read <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)
```

how can I build a list of database columns to try and identify what joins to what?
as a start I want to build a list of distinct columns names across all the dataframes in my list of dataframes.

Comment: What is the format of the dumps?

Comment: .csvs of the table contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start by finding the most common column names in the list:

```
file_read <- list(data.frame(id=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), x=c(1,3,6), w = 1:9), 
              data.frame(id=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), x=c(2,4,7), y = 10:18),
              data.frame(id=rep(c("b","c","d"),each=3), t=c(4,8,0), x=c(5,6,7), z = 1:9)
              )
```

For the distinct columns names:

```
distinctColumns <- unique(unlist(lapply(file_read, names)))
```

Now to count the number of times each column name appears:

```
table(unlist(lapply(file_read, names)))

## id  t  w  x  y  z 
##  3  1  1  3  1  1
```

**EDIT:**
There's probably a more efficient way of doing this, but here is the easiest/fastest way I could think of finding which tables have a specific column name:

```
listElements <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(file_read))
{ 
  tmp <- rep(i, length(lapply(file_read, function(x) which(distinctColumns %in% names(x)))[[i]]))
  listElements <- c(listElements, tmp)
}
names(listElements) <- distinctColumns[unlist(lapply(file_read, function(x) which(distinctColumns %in% names(x))))]
df <- data.frame(colNames = names(listElements), dfNumber = listElements)
df[df$colNames=="id",]

##  colNames dfNumber
##        id        1
##        id        2
##        id        3


df[df$colNames=="z",]

## colNames dfNumber
##        z        3
```

Comment: how can pick a column name and see what tables it's in then?